# glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES where can I get reference of this function?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am reading a book about iPhone game development, it uses some functions start with 'gl' and ends with 'OES'.
like this:
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES
Where can I get reference of these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/

In your case http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetRenderbufferParameteriv.xml

The OES suffix just marks it as being specific to OpenGL-ES (OES).

Answer (score 1):

you can find the man pages for OpenGL ES on the Khronos website:

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/

As far as I know the OES extension was removed as of OpenGL ES 2.0.
Hope this helps.